# Property of Distance to Nearest Integer

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove if $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ with $x+y+z=0$ in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, then
\begin{align*}
\|x\|+\|y\|+\|z\|=2\max(\|x\|,\|y\|,\|z\|)
\end{align*}
or

\begin{align*}
\|x\|+\|y\|+\|z\|=1
\end{align*}
with $\|x\|$ is the distance of $x$ to nearest integer.

I can only see $\|x\|+\|y\|+\|z\|=1$, and haven't found a way to get $\|x\|+\|y\|+\|z\|=2\max(\|x\|,\|y\|,\|z\|)$. Thank you.

Comment: I'm curious where this problem comes from.

Comment: @TravorLZH I am attending a course, not officially, in a university in Italy, and this is one of the homework problem. I am not mandatory to doing this, but I am curious about this problem.

Comment: To ensure that I understand correctly, is this asking you to analyze the solution of $x+y+z\in\mathbb Z$ for $x,y,z\in[0,1)$?

Comment: @TravorLZH yes you can think the problem like that